# Send email with log file as attachment

Tags: shell, hadoop, oozie, cloudera-cdh

I am using Hadoop (CDH 5.4.8) to process the unstructured data and after successful processing I want to send a mail notification to the concerned team with log file as attachment.

CDH 5.4.8 Oozie does not support attachment feature in email action. So I want to do this using shell script. Please let me know the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily send an email from within a shell by piping a complete mail message (header and body) into *sendmail*. This assumes that the host you're doing this is properly configured with a mail transfer agent (e.g. *sendmail* or *postfix*) to send email messages.

The easiest way to send email with an attachment is to create a simple template message in your mail user agent (e.g. *Thunderbird*), and copy its contents as a template with the *view source* command. Modify that template to suit your needs and place it in the shell script.

Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat <<\EOF |
To: Ramesh <ramesh@example.com>
From: Diomidis Spinellis <dds@aueb.gr>
Subject: Here are your Hadoop results
Message-ID: <5700BF28.2070500@aueb.gr>
Date: Sun, 3 Apr 2016 09:58:48 +0300
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="------------030303090406090809090501"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--------------030303090406090809090501
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

The attachment contains your Hadoop results.


--------------030303090406090809090501
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
 name="data"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="data"

HviDNR105+2Tr0+0fsx3OyzNueQqPuAXl9IUrafOi7Y=
--------------030303090406090809090501--
EOF
sendmail ramesh@example.com
```

To configure a fixed message with actual data, replace the parts you want to modify with commands that generate them. (Note the missing backslash from the here document `EOF` marker.)

```
#!/bin/sh
cat <<EOF |
To: Ramesh <ramesh@example.com>
From: Diomidis Spinellis <dds@aueb.gr>
Subject: Here are your Hadoop results
Message-ID: <5700BF28.2070500@aueb.gr>
Date: $(date -R)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="------------030303090406090809090501"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--------------030303090406090809090501
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

The attachment contains your Hadoop results.


--------------030303090406090809090501
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
 name="data"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="data"

$(base64 binary-data-file.dat)
--------------030303090406090809090501--
EOF
sendmail ramesh@example.com
```

Comment: thanks Diomidis, its working fine in local mode. Now I would like to test it in Oozie shell action.

Comment: if I have a file named "exmaple.csv". I need to place that name in both name="exmaple.csv" and filename="exmaple.csv"?? or what should I write in "data". And in case I am trying to send an xlsx file how should I modify the Content-Type and other parameters. I really would appreciate if you could share a link or similar with more information about the this. Thanks

Comment: I suggest that you send an attachment to yourself through your email client, and then look at the message source code.